# What is the best way to test Metal - MBPr late 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I just finished upgrading from 10.10 to 10.11 and so far its allot more smooth and responsive.

I was just wondering if theres any particular games or apps which utilise the new Metal gfx technology which I can checkout now. Anything that really showcases the new technology :)

I play Guildwars 2 a little, will non Metal games benefit?

And/or is there a way to know if my Macbook is using Metal or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As yet there aren't any games from the big dev companies utilising Metal, although companies like Blizzard are testing support and will update theirs accordingly in the 'next 6 months'

Those running 10.11 El Capitan can check whether their GPU supports Metal with this app:
[Metal Capability Test App](http://macminer.fabulouspanda.com/blog/index.php?post/2015/10/02/Does-your-Mac-support-Apple-s-new-Metal-API)